# Why can't I run sudo -g?

Tags: linux, redhat, sudo, groups

```
$ sudo -u fish -g fish bash
Sorry, user steve is not allowed to execute '/bin/bash' as fish:fish on myserver.
$ sudo -u fish bash
$ groups
fish
```

What's the -g option meant to be used for, and why I can't use it? RHEL btw.

Comment: what does your /etc/sudoers file look like?

Comment: steve   ALL=(ALL)       ALL

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Presumably because your sudoers file does not specify this. It is the difference between two lines like these: the first is the default but the second also allows you to run commands as any group, which is what you want.

- steve      ALL=(ALL) ...
- steve      ALL=(ALL:ALL) ...

Comment: Or just ALL:fish, or whatever.

Comment: Thanks - in this case, it makes no difference whether I run it "as any group", but I was interested to know why. As noted in my comment to my Q, the line in sudoers is exactly as you guessed.

Answer (score 5):

A wild man page appears!

> -g group    Normally, sudo sets the primary group to the one specified by the passwd
>                 database for the user the command is being run as (by default, root).  The -g
>                   (group) option causes sudo to run the specified command with the primary
>                   group set to group.  To specify a gid instead of a group name, use #gid.
>                   When running commands as a gid, many shells require that the '#' be escaped
>                   with a backslash ('\').  If no -u option is specified, the command will be
>                   run as the invoking user (not root).  In either case, the primary group will
>                   be set to group.

You probably can't use it because you don't have permission to.  If I'm reading the `sudoers`(5) manpage right, you need to explicitly specify a group list to to the `Runas_user` part of the sudoers entry in order to be able to use `-g`:

> If only the first is specified, the command may be run as any user in the
>   list but no -g option may be specified.